# How to collect parameters from a .cgi URL into multiple strings in iOS objC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, url

I'm trying to collect the parameters from my ip camera and pass them into individual strings in Objective-C (an iOS app). When I enter the following URL in any web browser: [http://192.168.1.10:92/get_camera_params.cgi] the following is displayed onto the screen:

> var resolution=32;
>   var brightness=136;
>   var contrast=4;
>   var mode=2;
>   var flip=3;
>   var fps=0;

I would like to collect and pass this values into my own strings such as:

> myResolution = 32;
>   myBrightness = 136;
>   ...................

My guess is that I need to somehow convert the response of the URL into a string and somehow break that string into an array of strings or 6 strings and collect the data in between "=" and ";" in individual strings?

Even though the actual values are Int's, the values must be stored in individual strings for my further code compatibility.

As much as it looks easy, I'm not sure how to approach this, I had a good go at it but didn't advance to anything that is worth putting here on the forum.

Please help with an example.
I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the response ist non-html, the following should work:

```
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSCharacterSet* charSetToReplace = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";\r"];

    // get content from url
    NSString* urlContent = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.10:92/get_camera_params.cgi"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    // split content into rows
    NSArray* lines = [urlContent componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for(NSString* line in lines)
    {
        //split row
        NSArray* comps = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];

        if(comps.count < 2)
           continue;


        // [comp objectAtIndex:0] is the value left of =
        // [comp objectAtIndex:1] is the value right of =

        // left string without the 'var '
        NSString* varName = [[comps objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"var " withString:@""];

        // right string with trimming the ';'
        int varValue = [[[comps objectAtIndex:1] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:charSetToReplace] intValue];

        // write into dictionary
        [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",varValue] forKey:varName];
    }

    // as int
    int myResolution = [[dict objectForKey:@"resolution"] intValue];
    int myBrightness = [[dict objectForKey:@"brightness"] intValue];

    // or as String
    NSString* myResolutionStr = [dict objectForKey:@"resolution"];
    NSString* myBrightnessStr = [dict objectForKey:@"brightness"];

    // and so on ...
```

Comment: I just noticed you have an answer to my question. I'll try your solution and I'll let you know how I went. Thanks for now @griz

Comment: it looks good as in no syntax errors but a runtime error:                        *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x18b0012 0x1623e7e 0x1865b44 0x1ed72 0x64c817 0x64c882 0x59ba25 0x59bdbf 0x59bf55 0x5a4f67 0x568fcc 0x569fab 0x57b315 0x57c24b 0x56dcf8 0x2a8ddf9 0x2a8dad0 0x1825bf5 0x1825962 0x1856bb6 0x1855f44 0x1855e1b 0x5697da 0x56b65c 0x60ed 0x20b8725)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception      @griz

Comment: if I change 'int varValue = [[[comps objectAtIndex:1]' with 'int varValue = [[[comps objectAtIndex:0]' I don't get the runtime error however brightness and resolution value comes up as 0. Bright=0 and Resol=0

Comment: maybe there is an empty line in the response. i added "if(comps.count < 2) continue;" to the code so the exception should not be thrown.

Comment: Works Now ! like a charm. I can't see any actual blank lines at the beginning but this is definitely the solution. Thanks a lot @griz